# JQuery DataTables not working unless table is blank

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When a table has 0 entries in it, the new sorting, paginating, and searching features work correctly. I've been working at this for hours. How do I get that functionality with a non-blank table?

[image]

But when there are entries in the table, all of that stops working:

[image]

The little sorting arrows appear, but they don't do anything when clicked.

Here's how I installed the gem:

application.js

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3

$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

application.css

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
```

gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
gem 'will_paginate'
```

the table looks like this in the view:

```
<table id='guides' class='table'>
  <thead>
    bla bla
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    bla bla
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: In `application.js` you use the selector `.datatable` but in the html example the class is `table`. Is that just a typing error?

Comment: Ah... Let me change that up and see what happens.

Comment: @GSP - Unfortunately, that did nothing. Everything works fine when there are no entries in the table.

Comment: On an off chance, make sure your HTML is valid. No unbalanced tags or anything like that. The fact that it breaks with content means, to me, that something specific about your table is the problem. Also, use firebug (http://getfirebug.com/ ) or something like that to ensure that you don't have any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Okay cool. Do you know of any tools for checking unbalanced tags?

Comment: You could also try returning just a single row into the table and see if it always fails with data or if there's a specific row that's causing the problem.

Comment: So far, no unclosed tags. Let me try testing one row.

Comment: I've checked the form of my table and it's correct. It works with only the `<thead>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. There were more `<td>` than `<th>`